# Reading multi-line json from s3 to dataframe

Tags: json, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I feel like I can't be the first to ask this question, but I can't find anything similar enough. My question is simple: What's the most efficient way to read a multi-line json from s3 into a pandas DataFrame?

The current approach I'm looking to replace is this:

```
obj = self.s3.Object(bucket, key)
df = pd.read_json(obj.get()["Body"].read(),orient='index', lines=True)
```

This sucks. I am running this job on kubernetes and it's sucking up around 20GB mem for a 1.8GB file.
My current revision is this:

```
obj = s3.Object(bucket, key)
file_content = obj.get()['Body'].read()
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [json.loads(line) for line in obj.get()['Body'].read().splitlines()]
)
```

This seems to work much faster (and it doesn't oom).

Any better approaches?

Bonus points for edge cases:
I think my approach covers all multi-line jsons by default and if it's compressed, I can just wrap the `obj.get()['Body'].read()` in a function.

Comment: do you need the object or can you use multipart download then read into a dataframe?

Comment: You have `lines=True` but no `chunksize`, so the file is read into memory all at once. Try setting a `chunksize` and read the json like so: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#line-delimited-json

Comment: I wanted to avoid writing the file to local and then ingesting it to pandas, but maybe that's somehow more efficient? I do think most of the latency and bloat is in read_json and not the download though. I will try the chunksize again and compare.